# Sort rows of a matrix by the first element in the row C

Tags: c, sorting, matrix

I have an matrix:

```
3  3 -1 -1
1  1  1 -1
6  6  6  6
0 -1 -1 -1
```

What I need is this output:

```
0 -1 -1 -1
1  1  1 -1
3  3 -1 -1
6  6  6  6
```

How can I proprely sort it like this?

Comment: [How to ask about homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Ask about *specific* problems with your *existing* implementation. Admit that the question is homework. Be aware of school policy regarding outside help. Never use code you don't understand.

Comment: Is your matrix in `int [][]` / `int **` ?

Comment: it's actually a matrix of structures,but you can consider it as int[][] too.

Comment: Sort by using the qsort.

Comment: You could use a row index to allow the qsort to only sort two columns, no matter how long the rows, but that kind of optimization is only worth it with large matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you. You should do the commented parts yourself to get the result.

```
#define RAW_NUM 4
#define COL_NUM  4  

int main () {
    int ** matrix = malloc (RAW_NUM * sizeof (int *));
    // you should be sure about successful allocation
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i < RAW_NUM; i++) {
        matrix [i]= malloc (COL_NUM * sizeof (int);
        // you should be sure about successful allocation
    }
    // fill the matrix here
    for (i=0; i < RAW_NUM - 1; i++) {
        for (j=i +1; j < RAW_NUM; i++) 
        if (*matrix [i] > *matrix [j])
       {
           // please swap matrix [i] and matrix [j] here
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting it so if anyone who is interested in Python might find it useful.

```
#input array
array = [[5,8], [1,2], [2,3], [7,9], [4,6]]
#sorting array according to first element of intervals. 
array.sort(key = lambda x:x[0])
```